# What does "evaluate" mean when used in Mathematical problems?

Tags: synonyms, mathematics, meaning

When solving Mathematical problems, I usually come across with titles like:

> Evaluate the expression below.
>   Evaluate this: ∜[(log<sub>2</sub>(48 / 3) + 1)<sup>2</sup> - 9]
>   Evaluate the following integral.

When I look up at dictionary, it says:

> *to evaluate*:
>   1. to determine or set the value  or amount of; appraise: to evaluate property.
>   2. to judge or determine the significance, worth, or quality of; assess: to evaluate the results of an experiment.

I looks like to be a sophisticated word from commercial terminology. Why don't they use a simpler an more common verb instead of it? Like these ones:

> <s>Evaluate</s> Find the value of the expression below.
>   <s>Evaluate</s> Simplify this: ∜[(log<sub>2</sub>(48 / 3) + 1)<sup>2</sup> - 9]
>   <s>Evaluate</s> Solve the following integral.

Is there a reason for preferring this verb over its alternatives?

Comment: The answer is `2`.

Comment: The answer is `1`. Evaluate: *determine the value of*.

Comment: The answer is `2`. log(48/3)/log2=4 | (4+1)^2=25 | (25-9)^(1/4)=2

Comment: Generally, in math, _evaluate_ means to provide a numerical solution (in real or complex numbers, depending) to an expression, if possible; if not possible, to reduce it to a standard description in lowest terms, or at least an algorithm for producing such in minimal time.

Comment: How old are your maths books / papers?

Comment: "Evaluate" is preferred over its simpler alternatives for the exact same reason you preferred the fancy words "sophisticated", "commercial", "terminology", "prefer", and "alternative" over *their* simpler alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

According to [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=evaluate), the term *evaluate* was originally used only in mathematics, and its usage then spread to its current use in commercial technology. It would have originally just meant "find the value of".

As for the alternatives you suggest, most of them don't work.

- solve the integral ...

You can't solve an integral. You can only solve an equation or a problem.

- simplify the integral ...

You can simplify an expression, but mathematicians don't talk about "simplifying an integral". To me, finding the value of an integral is too complicated an operation to use "simplify" rather than "evaluate".

- find the value of the integral ...

This works fine, but it's four words instead of one.